Quill.js in error with webpack Encore integration
I'm encountering an issue while integrating Quill.js into my webpack setup. When trying to use Quill in my project, I'm getting the following error:
Uncaught Error: Module parse failed: Unexpected token (28:18)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type, currently, no loaders are configured to process this file. See https://webpack.js.org/concepts#loaders```
|
| class Quill {

static DEFAULTS = {
| bounds: null,
| modules: {

It seems to be related to how webpack is handling Quill.js files, particularly with the static class field syntax used in Quill.
I use Webpack with Encore in my Symfony project. (php 7.4 and symfony 5.4)
I've tried various configurations and searched for solutions online, but I'm still encountering this issue. Could someone please provide guidance on how to resolve this error and properly integrate Quill.js into my webpack setup?
Thanks in advance for your help!
I aim to integrate Quill.js seamlessly into my Webpack setup so that I can use it to create rich text editors within my Symfony application. This integration should allow me to leverage Quill's features without encountering any errors during the build process. Ultimately, I want to be able to include Quill.js in my project and use it to enhance the text editing experience for my users, all while maintaining a smooth development workflow with webpack.
